# How many characters does bin2hex(random_bytes()) depending on input?

Tags: php, encryption, cryptography, byte

I'm using the following code to genrate a simple UID for my app:

```
private function _createUid() {
    $bytes = random_bytes(128);
    $uid = bin2hex($bytes);

    return $uid;
}
```

By doing this, the result of `_createUid()` will be a 256 character string. My question is, will this string always be `256` characters if run on the same server, I'm aware of some differences on different servers. Also, is one byte equal to two characters?

Any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: why not use uniqid()?

Comment: @nogad it's not cryptographically random and could possibly repeat.

Comment: How could it not be 256 characters? In hex a byte is always expressed as 2 characters.

Comment: @zaph alright, so when using hex it will always be 2 characters per byte?

Comment: @PaulCrovella thank you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In hex a byte is always expressed as 2 characters.

Hexadecimal representation of a byte is a sequence of two character pairs. The first character represents the most significant 4 bits and the second character represents the least significant 4 bits of a byte.

Comment: Slightly off-topic, but what would be a suitable character length for a authentication key if you are using `random_bytes`? I was thinking of doing `bin2hex(random_bytes(30))` and was wondering if I'd need to increase the length more?

Comment: @Script47 1. It depends on the use case. 2. Best asked as a question, probably on [Information Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/).